# Batch processing away status for multiple users

Tags: nest-api

We are working on integrating a home security camera into the nest API and we are wondering if there is a way to get home/away status for multiple users via one web request?

We would like to monitor the home/away status at a global level and update our cameras armed/disarmed state accordingly without relying on a direct connection between the camera and nest API for each user individually.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful downvote, but the reason I am asking this general support question is this is the only way to contact nest developer support.

"If you have a technical question, please go to Stack Overflow and search or post with the tag "nest-api". Nest engineers are continuously responding to posts, and they'll get back to you shortly."

Comment: Nest engineers are continuously responding to posts, and they'll get back to you shortly - Yeah, about that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at multiplexing:
https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/multiplex-overview

I dont really understand the group stuff myself and am still trying to get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, multiplexing is currently the only solution for getting data from multiple accounts in one request.  Multiplexing also only supports streaming, so essentially it is one long request with server sent events returning states for these tokens.

Be aware that [Nest's Developer Terms of Service](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/tos#iii-prohibitions) prohibit "Aggregate control of Nest products, services, or Customer Data across multiple households except to the extent Nest permits control of multiple homes in a single Nest account."

Therefore, it is prohibited to use any data from one Nest account to control devices in another Nest account.